# Generate unique integer key for set of lists

Tags: arrays, vector, hash, set

I have a number of integer vectors all the same length. They could contain any signed int16.
I need to create a single unique number for each vector, but vectors which have the same content **must** be given the same number.
E.g the following vectors:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[6, 2, 4, 1]
```

might be assigned the numbers 2, 2 and 4.

Also order counts. So the vectors

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[2, 1, 4, 3]
```

should get different values.

Is there any reliable way to calculate a single number for a such a set of vectors?

To sum up the value must:

- Be the same for vectors which are exactly the same (order counts!)
- Be guaranteed to be unique for different values
  The value must be calculated for one vector at a time...i.e you are given a vector, you get the value, then you get the next vector and so on.

The whole purpose of this is that Im interested in an alternative way of indexing distinct vectors to e.g adding them all to an oredered set or similar.

Comment: You don't give much information about what the integers can contain. All of your examples lead to a very simple hash function: `[1, 2, 3, 4] => 1234`.

Comment: The range of the numbers is important here. To guarantee that the numbers are unique for every possible combination, you will have numbers as large as the vector length multiplied by the range (like in Phyolgenesis' example for a range of 10).

Comment: @Phylogenesis Could be any signed int16

Comment: If the integer key must be calculated given only one vector without knowledge of the other vectors then the simplest way is to concatenate the integers in the vector. This means that given a vector of size 4 with arbitrary 32bit integers the key must be a 4*32=128bit integer.

Comment: In that case, the best you can do is a 64-bit hash.

Answer (score 0):

To guarantee perfect uniqueness, you will have to compose a large number out of every single number. Given that you specified to allow signed int16 values you would get the following 64bit hash key:

```
[n1, n2, n3, n4] => n1 + n2*2^16 + n3*2^32 + n4*2^48
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...suppose you had multiple numbers (say up to 30). The integer is going to get too big there?

Comment: Yes in such a case, you won't be able to fit your hash into a numeric type. Instead, you could use a byte array with a size of 30*4. However, before using such monster hashcodes I would definitely question your approach. Is perfect uniqueness really necessary? Wouldn't a just "good" hashcode with proper hash collision handling be a better solution?